# How can I initialise a member array of objects that don't have a default constuctor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I'm supposed to initialise a member array of objects, in the occasion that the object does not have a default constructor (i.e. requires parameters).

For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() : 
      memberArray{bar(1), bar(3), bar(2)}   // **The compiler doesnt like this** 
   {}
private:
   Bar memberArray[3];
};


struct Bar
{
   Bar(std::int32_t param1) {  }
}
```

I'm using GCC 4.6.1, and compiling for c++11. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? (BTW. please don't suggest dynamically allocated memory, as I don't have it..)

Comment: gcc 4.6.1 is already old, in terms of the C++11 standard.  Can you try with 4.6.2 or bleeding-edge?

Comment: Also, post a minimal reproduction of the problem.  What you have now won't compile (inconsistent case, `struct Bar` used before declaration) and  we can't tell whether those problems are related to your error.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: It's very difficult for me to upgrade as the compiler's repackaged by a third-party (CodeSourcery) and 4.6.1 is what their latest version is built around. Is this a compiler problem then? Should it be possible in c++11?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I initialise a member std::array of objects that don't have a default constuctor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646428/how-can-i-initialise-a-member-stdarray-of-objects-that-dont-have-a-default-co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several problems: inconsistent case, use before declaration, missing semicolons, missing includes.  This is a lot closer:

```
struct Bar
{
   Bar(int param1) {  }
};

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() : 
      memberArray{Bar(1), Bar(3), Bar(2)}
   {}
private:
   Bar memberArray[3];
};
```

Comment: Thanks. That was pseudo-code to represent my actual problem and I really should have tried to compile it first.... A bigger mistake as that I was really using `std::array<Bar,3> memberArray` and this was causing the compilation error. By changing it to `Bar memberArray[3]` as above, the problem has gone.

Comment: @TimYorke: So, the question actually has _nothing at all_ to do with your real problem, and the solution was to actually use the code you posted?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Lesson learnt.. From now on, I will always compile my quoted code before I post.

Comment: @TimYorke : `std::array<>` should work just fine, you just may need an extra set of braces in the initializer since you're using aggregate initialization on `std::array<>`'s underlying C-array.